# How do I display data in a dynamically created page

Tags: 7

I have a form on the page that has multiple fields, one of which is a path (www.sample.com/PATH). With form data that I have, I need to forward to that dynamic page, and display form data (5 nodes for example).

This is the code I am using.

```
function MODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/URL_TO_SEE_FORM'] = array(
    'title' => 'Some title',
    'description' => 'Desc',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('MODULE_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}


function MODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['form_path'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Path'),
    '#size' => 60,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    'autocomplete_path' => FALSE,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  // other code that get's different data with ajax etc.

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function MODULE_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // some validation
}

function MODULE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $form_path = trim($form_state['values']['form_path']);

  $nodes = $form_state['values']['nodes'];
  // I need to get content from nodes ids whic should be easy

  // Need to set content to page under www.sample.com/$form_path

  $form_state['redirect'] = $form_path;
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it by using Views module.

On first submit, I would dynamically create view, and on each concurrent submit I would create additional view display (page).

Comment: I would recommend Views, especially now that it is in Core (for D8), in most cases where data needs to be displayed. It avoids the need of security testing, and is far easier to edit/modify/extend.